# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que una variable (tipo int) aumente una unidad cada semana?

Tags: java

Necesito que una variable aumente en una unidad cada semana para empezar un bucle desde un punto u otro. En esta parte del código itero entre diversas listas (una de tareas de casa y otra de personas) para poder asignar las tareas de casa a los usuarios. Necesito que cada semana se empiecen a asignar las tareas desde un usuario diferente, por lo que cada semana debe aumentar una variable.

```
int cont = 0;

for (int g = 0; g < ListTareas.size();g++){
            
    boolean comp = false;
         
    for (int i = 0; i+cont < ListUsuarios.size();i++){
        if(ListTareas.get(g).getEdadMin() <= ListUsuarios.get(i+cont).getEdad() && ListUsuarios.get(i+cont).getEdad() <= ListTareas.get(g).getEdadMax()){
                    
            JPanel selec = new JPanel();
            selec.setBackground(new Color(77, 216, 167));
                    
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            c.gridx = 1 + ListTareas.indexOf(ListTareas.get(g));
            c.gridy = 1 + cont + i;
            subpanel.add(selec, c);
                    
            cont = i + cont;
                
            for (int j=1; cont+j < ListUsuarios.size();j++){
                        
                JPanel vacio = new JPanel();
                vacio.setBackground(new Color(116, 139, 170));
                        
                c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
                c.gridx = 1 + ListTareas.indexOf(ListTareas.get(g));
                c.gridy = 1 + cont + j;
                subpanel.add(vacio, c);
            }
            comp = true;
            break;
        }else{
                  
            JPanel vacio = new JPanel();
            vacio.setBackground(new Color(116, 139, 170));
                    
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            c.gridx = 1 + ListTareas.indexOf(ListTareas.get(g));
            c.gridy = 1 + i + cont;
            subpanel.add(vacio, c);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no entiendo el problema al sumar 1 a una variable...

Comment: La variable debe aumentar cada vez que pase una semana, pero no sé cómo puedo saber cuando ha pasado la semana

Comment: Hola MauriINS, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos un poco más de contexto, podrías mostrarnos el código sobre el que estás trabajando?.

Comment: Ya está, no he puesto el código entero por practicidad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clase **LocalDate** te permite sumarle días a una fecha.
Primero creas la fecha

Si es la actual:

```
LocalDate hoy = LocalDate.now();
```

Si es otra:

```
LocalDate fecha = LocalDate.parse( "2022-12-31" );
```

Si es otra y usas otro formato:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateformatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/yyyy" );
Localdate fecha = dateformatter.format( "31/12/2022" ));
```

Ahora vamos con tu problema:

```
int variableParaModificar = 0;
LocalDate fechaA = LocalDate.now();

   // creamos una nueva fecha 7 días posterior. 
LocalDate fechaB = fechaA.plusDays( 7 );

   // recorremos un año
for( int i = 0; i < 365; i++ ) {

       // comparamos las dos fechas.
    if( fechaA.isEqual( fechaB ) ) {

           // si son iguales aumentamos la variable y le sumamos 7 a la fecha objetivo.
        variableParaModificar += 1;

           // volvemos a poner a 7 días vista la fecha objetivo
        fechaB.plusDays( 7 );
    }
    hagoAlgo();

       // actualizamos la fecha.
    fechaA.plusDays( 1 );
}
```

El método **plusDays()** agrega la cantidad de días especificada como parámetro (si es negativa, resta los días).